# Get connection pool stats from Knex.js

Tags: knex.js

I'm getting an intermittent error from my Knex driver:

`TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?`

I'm guessing that, either my RDS Aurora instance became temporarily unreachable from the server, or that my connection pool is running out during a particularly busy boost of traffic. I'd like to log and graph the available vs occupied connections in the connection pool, to see I am indeed running out of connections, and if there's a particular point when connection usage spikes. But I can't seem to find out from Google if there's a way to get the number of available connections from Knex or its pool manager. Is this possible? If not, is there some other way to log stats about my connection pool?

I see that there's an option that I can pass to the connection pool init `log` and it takes a boolean. I'm using `Winston` to ship my logs to Loggly, instead of just shipping the contents of stdout. I don't know that "log" attribute would log the events I'm interested in, but in any case I'd need to get that information as data so that I can send it to Loggly in a meaningful way.

Comment: I realized that my needs were satisfied by node-postgres instead of Knex, and node-postgres makes it easy to access stats about the pool. I no longer need the answer to this question, but I'm leaving it up here in case someone else does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have some information about how connections are fetched/returned to pool by running your application with environment variable `DEBUG=knex:*` set.

Knex is using tarn.js as its pool implementation. There are some methods for getting information of pool resources https://github.com/vincit/tarn.js/ which are listed in the end of the page.

```
// returns the number of non-free resources
pool.numUsed()

// returns the number of free resources
pool.numFree()

// how many acquires are waiting for a resource to be released
pool.numPendingAcquires()

// how many asynchronous create calls are running
pool.numPendingCreates()
```

Pool instance can be found through `knex.client.pool`.

```
const knex = require('knex')({ client: 'pg', connection: 'postgres://knex_test' });
knex.client.pool.numPendingCreates(); // returns 0
```

Comment: The `DEBUG=knex:*` tip was a life-saver for me. My problem was not related to connection pool, but rather that I was calling `knex.destroy()` in the wrong place. This debug command helped me quickly see this problem!